# Unable to generate native image using GraalVM

Tags: quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I was trying to create a custom runtime Lambda using quarkus and GraalVM and in that process(https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda), I was trying to build a native-image for the Gradle application. I have GraalVM(20.2.0) and native-image(20.2.0) installed on my windows machine along with the JAVA 11 and Docker.
When i run the command to generate the native image I was getting this error.
The command which i have used is
**gradlew clean build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:20.2.0-java11 -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.enable-http-url-handler=true**

error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=quay.io%2Fquarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-native-image&tag=20.2.0-java11: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
Unable to get GraalVM version from the native-image binary.
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running
See 'docker run --help'.

> Task :quarkusBuild FAILED

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':quarkusBuild'.
> io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
> [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
> at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:307)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:936)
> at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
> at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 127
> at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:520)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:276)

Can anyone help me with this issue.Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with GraalVM. And something to do with Docker on Windows. Can you try the same build using WLS?

Comment: Are you able to "clean package -Pnative", without performing the docker image generation?

Answer (score 4):

I faced more or less the same issue with maven package in Windows:

```
mvn clean package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel:21.2-java11
```

(...)

```
error during connect: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2FdockerDesktopLinuxEngine/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=quay.io%2Fquarkus%2Fubi-quarkus-native-image&tag=21.2-jav
a11": open //./pipe/dockerDesktopLinuxEngine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Solution: I've checked status of Docker daemon ([Docker Desktop in Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/)) and it was simply not running (probably because of lack of memory). I've restarted Docker, tried again the maven package and the docker pull worked as expected.

Comment: struggled with this about 2 hours than I found out my docker wasn't running

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Docker installation and Try following command.

> DockerCli.exe -SwitchDeamon

It will switch your container from windows to Linux and if there are no installations are there to support the switch it will throw you the error the along with link.
please go through the link and complete the installation.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you need to install : https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe

and run the command :  ".\mvnw package -P native" with your respective repo from your  Visual studio.

steps : https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image

Use a 64-bit hosted developer command prompt : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-enable-a-64-bit-visual-cpp-toolset-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#use-a-64-bit-hosted-developer-command-prompt-shortcut

Comment: Please stop posting the same answer to multiple questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73521269/7733418 https://stackoverflow.com/a/73521324/7733418 https://stackoverflow.com/a/73521287/7733418